# White bar, and then text watermark?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics

I would like to apply a watermark to images.

At the moment, I am trying to use this code, but it's failing on different sized images:

```
public void AddWaterMark(string filePath, string watermarkText)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(
        MapPath(GlobalVariables.UploadPath + "/" + filePath));
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    Font font = new Font("Alial Black", 40);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb(50, 241, 235, 105);
    StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat
                                {
                                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Near, 
                                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
                                };
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    gr.DrawString(watermarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color), 
        new Point(20, img.Height - 60), stringFormat);

    img.Save(MapPath(GlobalVariables.UploadPath + "/w_" + filePath));
}
```

Sometimes the font goes off the bottom. I want it to be text along the bottom of the image.

How do I ensure it doesn't go off the bottom?

Also, I want to enhance it slightly. I want to make a white, but transparent bar across the full length of the bottom of the image, and then write black text over it. Is this possible with drawing? So, a bar across the bottom of the image, maybe 60 pixels high, and in the middle of the 60px, I want text written (left aligned).

I am also finding the text moves arounf, depending on the file size

Here's an image that works:
http://www.listerhome.com/fulldisplay.aspx?imageid=100055

Bur sometimes, when I uploaded higher resolution images, I get this:
http://www.listerhome.com/fulldisplay.aspx?imageid=100060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MeasureString` function to calculate string size.

```
SizeF stringSize = gr.MeasureString(watermarkText, font, img.Width - 40);
gr.DrawString(watermarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color), 
    new RectangleF(20, img.Height - stringSize.Height, img.Width - 40, stringSize.Height),
    stringFormat);
```

Comment: This adds a rectangle, which is very helpful, thanks. But I am finding that on larger images, the font is larger than when I load smaller images.

Comment: Can you post image samples (large and small)?

Comment: I can supply the URL of my test site?

Comment: "The image has been removed". Sorry we have different time zones.